# I think parsing this type of json response is impossible in Dart. How can I convert this json to Dart Class?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, dio

An API gives me json response like this:

```
[{"version": "v3.5"}, {"setup": true}, {"address": "e7d398b"}, {"connected": true}, {"active": true}, {"id": "ce7143"}, {"genuine": true}]
```

As you can see, this is a list of objects. I tried parsing it like this using quicktype generated model class-

```
List<Result>.from(result.map((x) => Result.fromJson(x)));
```

But it's failing since each of the objects are of different types.

I think I have to convert each of the objects in the array one by one to Dart classes and add it to an Array.

So I tried this (I am using dio) -

```
final result = response.data;
var b = List.empty(growable: true);
result.map((x) => b.add(x));
```

But it's not working.

How can I atleast access the elements of the array?

Solved

---

Inspired by the accepted answer, I was able to generate corresponding Dart Class. Never thought can looping through a map is possible, IDE was not giving any clue.

```
final result = response.data;
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
      for (var e in result) {
        map.addAll(e);
      }
      final finalResult = Result.fromJson(map);
      return finalResult;
```

Comment: Dart version? "but it's faliling since each [...]" how is it failing? what message? "But it is not working" what is "working" for you? what do you wanna do, achieve?

Comment: See https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more for the last question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74924517/19945688) mentioned above, there is no JSON you can not parse with Dart.
In your case, you have a `List` of `Map` objects. What you can do is:

```
   final data = jsonDecode(json) as List;

    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};

    for (var e in data) {
      map.addAll(e);
    }
    print(map);

 //prints

{version: v3.5, setup: true, address: e7d398b, connected: true, active: true, id: ce7143, genuine: true}
```

If you're using the `dio` flutter package it returns decoded `json`, no
need to call for `jsonDecode`.
I recommend using [json code generation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) if you face large `json` instead of relying on quicktype generated models.

Answer (score 1):

There's **no** JSON that isn't parsable with Dart. But you might end up with a data structure that requires careful navigation. Classes make it easier, but there isn't always a class structure for any arbitrary JSON, and maybe *that's* your point. In that case, you'll have to navigate to the data of interest in an ad-hoc fashion.

Comment: Greate points, but I think this answer could have been a comment instead.

Comment: I originally wrote it as a comment, but it felt a bit too long for a comment.